# How to null check expression in angulajs(View)

Tags: angularjs

I need to display a div based on some value (It should not be null or empty in angularjs. I have tried `ng-if`, but i need to check for expression.

**How to achieve this ?**

**Eg:** `{{documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath}}`

I need to check whether this expression is not null and then display the div, if its not null.

I have tried, `<div ng-if="!{{documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath}}">` But i am getting the below error,

```
Error: angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 3 of the expression [!{{documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath}}] starting at [{documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath}}].
```

Comment: did you try `ng-if=documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath`

Comment: `ng-show="documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath"`??

Comment: ng-if="documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath !== null"

Answer (score 0):

A strict check can be applied in your directive like so:

```
ng-if="[null, ''].indexOf(documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath) === -1"
```

In Javascript null and an empty string are falsy, this can be **elegantly** written as pointed out by @Edison:

```
ng-if="documentList.iloadsDocuments.docPath"
```